# Подсобите с проблемными ситуациями в области распределенных вычислений на мобильных устройствах

Tags: android

Привет всем!) 
Работаю над магистерской, ну как работаю... Пытаюсь что-то сделать.
Вообщем, недавно начали появляться распределенные вычислительные системы, основанные на мобильниках(Android). Я интересуюсь этой темой уже год(еще был бакалавром). Проблема, не могу самостоятельно найти явную проблемную ситуацию в этой области.
Есть какие-то проблемные ситуации, которые пригодны для исследований(магистерская)? Специалисты, что скажете???
Может алгоритмы распараллеливания исследовать? Не?

Заранее благодарен за ответы:)

Answer (score 4):

Примеры проблемны аспектов:

1. При переносе с x86 на ARM ненадёжный код, которые полагался на то, насколько атомарно исполняются инструкции в x86 может сломаться в ARM. В ARM модель многопоточного доступа к памяти более слабая по сравнению с x86;
2. Сеть. Стационарные компьютеры обычно надёжно подключены к сети, а мобильные могут использовать дорогую, медленную и ненадёжную сеть. IP-адрес может меняться во время вычислния;
3. Батарея. Мобильные устройства обычно работают от батареи, заряд и ресурс которой нужно экономить;
4. Ждущий режим. Если специально не указывать, то по умолчанию устройство в него переходит и вычисления прерываются;
5. Цена за "флопсы". Мобильные устройства обычно дороже таких же по вычислительной мощности стационарных;
6. Надёжность вычислений. Мобильные устройста не очень ориентированы на надёжность (серверная память и т.д.);
7. Безопасность. Мобильные устройства проще украсть.

Для некоторых применений могут быть однако преимущества:

1. Доступность датчиков (камера, GPS, освещённость, положение и т.д.);
2. Скрытность (смартфон легче спрятать и он бесшумный);

P.S. если на этом ответе будет основана научная работа, следует поставить из неё сюда ссылку.

Comment: Хорошо :) Если что, предлагайте варианты) Мне всё интересно)